# iOS set two button next eachother with padding

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to place two buttons on the same line next to each other and make equally big. So not based on the word length. I have simple no clue how to do this in the storyboard.

I am able to this this in the code through couple calculations. But I want to know if it is possible through the storyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve as following:

[image]

Set the padding as you need. In the example, I use 20 points. Enter the required values, and tick the red lines to enable the constraints for addition. Also tick "Equal Widths" (and possible "Equal Heights") and finally, click the "Add Constraints" button.

Comment: Thank as far as I can tell this is the solution. But I do not have that option you are pressing to add a constraint. I'm knew to this could you just tell me where that option is?

Comment: Make sure you have autolayout enabled. In the right inspector, on the first tab, there is a checkbox "Use Autolayout". Make sure it is ticked.

Comment: Cheers! Just remember, that once autolayout is enabled, you will have to use it for all your controls.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by playing about with the constraints of the two UIButtons in the storyboard viewer. The constraint you'll want specifically is "Equal Widths" with both buttons selected as this will set a constraint on both buttons to not resize larger than one another.

Comment: That solved half the problem, so thanks. I didn't know I could select two views and set that. But how do I make each button as big as it can be in current orientation with margin between

Comment: As Leo Nathan mentioned below, you can do this by using padding. This will ensure that your buttons will grow as your orientation dictated but will leave a minimum amount of space that you can set. The same can be done to leave space between your buttons. Xcode 5 comes with some really nice tools to help you use Autolayout compared to Xcode 4, can't think of any tutorials that show them in action but I highly recommend to play about with them to get used to them. :)